# Creating new files on top of existing ones

Tags: windows, powershell

I am quite new to PowerShell scripting.
I'm trying to create a PowerShell script which shall create new custom files in a given folder (Path)

Let's say that I've entered already my `$pfad` and my `$ext` (i.e .txt). And I've entered for `$anz`  the number `2`. My output in the folder would be like this:

"Created_File 1.txt" and "Created_File 2.txt"

```
#Enter Path where the files should be created
$pfad = Read-Host "Pfadeingabe "  

#Enter Number of files that should be generated
$anz = Read-Host "Anzahl an Dateien "

#Enter a file extension
$ext = Read-Host "Dateierweiterung (txt, pdf) "  

#Name of the standard created file
$name = "Created_File" 

#loop through the given number of files that should be created
for($i=1; $i -le $anz; $i++)
{
    #Check if the files already exist
    #if(Test-Path -Path "$pfad\$name $i.$ext" )
    #{
        #Code to create the given number of files with another name
    #}
    New-Item -Path $pfad -Name "$name $i.$ext" -ItemType "file"
}
```

Now that the files are already existing I want to check that in powershell which work with the if-statement within for-loop. 
Let's say I enter for `$anz` the number `2`. When my for-loop is now looping the if-statement checks that there are already 2 files with the same name existing.

What I want now is that the number continues. So that I have as Output "Created_File 3.txt" and "Created_File 4.txt" in my folder.
And if I enter for `$anz` 2 again then the output should continue like "Created_File 5.txt" and "Created_File 6.txt"

But I don't know how to do this. Do you can help me?

I hope you can understand my question and what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to solve this kind of issue, the most basic one (imho) would be to search for the number of existing file matching the file `$name` and counting from there:

```
#Enter Path where the files should be created
$pfad = Read-Host "Pfadeingabe "  

#Enter Number of files that should be generated
$anz = Read-Host "Anzahl an Dateien "

#Enter a file extension
$ext = Read-Host "Dateierweiterung (txt, pdf) "  

#Name of the standard created file
$name = "Created_File" 

$existingFileNumber = get-childitem -Path $pfad -Filter "$name *.txt" | Measure-Object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count

#loop through the given number of files that should be created
for($i=$existingFileNumber +1 ; $i -le [int]$anz + $existingFileNumber; $i++)
{
    New-Item -Path $pfad -Name "$name $i.$ext" -ItemType "file"
}
```

Comment: Ok. I've tried that code, but something strange happens. When I entered ```$pfad, $anz = 2 and $ext``` the for-loop creates 20 files from 1-20 even if the folder is empty.
I echoed the ```$anz and $i``` to see what's happening. As expected with 0 files in the folder ```$anz``` stays at 2, but ```$i``` even exceeds the number of ```$anz``` and does not break out of the loop.

Comment: This is because `Read-Host` saves `$anz` as a string, this way you add the "0" from `$existingFileNumber` as a character instead of the number. When you force the variable into `[int]` the addition works. (see the updated answer)

Comment: Oh yes. I totally forgot the declariation type of variables. This helped me a lot. Thank you very much